# java server application performance issues

Tags: java, performance, memory, jvm, file-descriptor

i am monitoring a java process that runs for a long period of time, the process uses G1 garbage collector.

those are my java options(runs in server mode):

```
-Xmx2048m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M -XX:MetaspaceSize=100m -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=400m
```

the process is a java websocket server which involves a lot of I/O with embedded tomcat in front of it.
according to java mission control the top heap usage reaches 1.7GB and after every GC cycle it decreases back to ~900MB.
the process runs in a docker container with 3.8GB of memory restriction.
when using `top -o %MEM` it shows that total RES is 2.6GB and never more.

i am noticing that after a heavy load of websockets connect/disconnect the process becomes really slow and unresponsive.

when i try to load this process again after 6-7 hours, while it's idle and "clean" of connections it responses after 6-7 seconds, while in the first load the response time was much lower ~2-3 seconds.

i thought it's file descriptors related but while checking with:

```
ls /proc/1/fd | wc -l
```

from inside the docker it shows all file descriptors released.

java version: 8u131
tomcat version: 8.5.60

this is how my heap looks like after 6 hours of load with no connections on the server:
[image]
and this is from JMC:
[image]

how can i investigate it further?

Answer (score 2):

Don't focus on the memory & garbage collection (yet) but identify what takes time in the request processing.
Is the time spent in your request handler code? Is it somewhere else?

If you can modify the code, you can simply add some println statements to start.
And/Or you can use a lightweight cpu profiler like https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler to get a CPU flame graph - [wall-clock profiling](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler#wall-clock-profiling) might be especially helpful for "off-cpu" analysis.